# Why doesn't FirebaseFirestore throw an exception deleting a non-existing file?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know when FirebaseFirestore does not delete file from remove:

```
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new 
  FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                           .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
                            .build();
  db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

//delet document from Cloud Firestore by documentId (is uniq name of doucument)
    db.collection(COLLECTION_PATH).document(documentId).delete()
```

I put non-existing id of document but task is isSuccessful. Is it correct behave?

Comment: Please provide full code you have used for Delete Document.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task is considered successful when the document no longer exists on the server. That means that the task is also successful if the document doesn't exist by the time your action gets to the server.

So what you're seeing is indeed the expected behavior. If you want to know if the document previously existed, use a transaction that fetches the document first, checks for existence, and then deletes it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new precondition option you can pass to delete calls so it fails if the document doesn't exist. [See firebase SDK docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/Precondition)

```
snap.ref.delete({ exists: true })
```